# Compare last entry price with current price

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to compare the lastEntry (last bought trade value) with the current trade. I only want make trades if the currentPrice (close) is lower min 10% and sell if higher than 1% than last bought trade. Never selling if current price is lower than last bought
`

Here is an example code but not working

```js
lastPriceEntry = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
calcPercent = ((float(lastPriceEntry) - float(close)) / float(lastPriceEntry)) * 100
buy = calcPercent >= 10 ? true : false
longentry = buy`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the strategy.position_avg_price built-in variable:

```
entryPercent = input(10, title="Entry Percent", type=input.float) / 100
exitPercent = input(1, title="Exit Percent", type=input.float) / 100

percentDiff = (close - strategy.position_avg_price) / strategy.position_avg_price

longCondition = percentDiff <= -entryPercent
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

exitLongCondition = percentDiff >= exitPercent
if (exitLongCondition)
    strategy.close("Long")
```

This script will enter a long trade when the current close price is at least 10% lower than the average entry price of the current position and exit the trade when the current close price is at least 1% higher than the average entry price.